# Как разрешить доступ к папке static на nginx (ubuntu)? Django + Gunicorn

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, virtualbox, gunicorn

Такая проблема, не загружаются статические файлы на сайте, созданном на django (gunicorn + nginx). Сервер Ubuntu на VirtualBox. При обращении в url (domain.com/static/) возникает ошибка 403 (forbidden), думаю, проблема в этом.

Код nginx.conf

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name 192.168.0.101;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        root /home/yasf/build;
}

location / {
include proxy_params;
proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Немного ошибся, указал код не того файла, но я исправил проблему. Суть в том, что нужно было просто в самом настоящем nginx.conf изменить 1 строку кода user www-data; на user "ваш юзернейм на ubuntu"; и все